# Embedded php css file not working

Tags: php, html, css

I have embedded my CSS file as PHP to make it more dynamic as shown in various examples online but I can't seem to get it working

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='myphpstylesheet.php'>
```

My PHP file which I added in the link

```
<?php
 $bgcolor = '#FF00FF';
 ?>

 <style>
 Div #container {
  Background-color: <?php echo $bgcolor ; ?>
 }
 </style>
```

My HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='myphpstylesheet.php'>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="container ">
     I am a div with lorem ipusum 
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But the color does not apply please help

Comment: what exactly are you trying to archive?

Comment: Where are you adding `Myphp file` into `Myhtml file` I dont see anything that would achieve that. ___<link here>___ does not tell us enough

Comment: I want to like change my css with php like embedded php css

Comment: Can you copy your embedding link ? What is the computed CSS file ? Did you looked it up in your browser ?

Comment: Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am adding it in the head the <link> part let me edit my question

Comment: No, I meant the comment to link in the html file. What excatly is:  <link here>

Comment: are you trying to make an embedded `php file` act like `css file` ??

Comment: `herf` !== `href`

Comment: i will assume you want output your style with php?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for the corrections in the typo i had a few of thoes in my main code as well

Comment: I was able to fix it using the headers form bobbyaxe answer i didn't know i had to specify a header thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some search on embedding css as php file, 
I don't really see the reason for this just use css as intended.

Anyway you can try these methods hope it fixes you problem also take note of `herf` and `href`as pointed out by Riggs Folly as they are not the same.

**METHOD 1**
You can edit your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` with this line

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .css`

the web server will now parse PHP code that is within the CSS files but i would
avoid messing with those at all costs.

**METHOD 2**
You can also include a PHP file, in the same manner as you include a CSS file

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php" media="screen">`

this should be done within the head of the HTML document that is the `<head></head>` tags

Then your style.php file should look something like this:

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor = "#555555";
   $CDNURL = "http://cdn.blahblah.net";
?>
```

Then your css file should look somthing like this:

```
#header {
   background: url("<?php echo $CDNURL; ?>/images/header-bg.png") no-repeat;
}
a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}

ul li a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Do i need another css file i thought that the point of this was not to use a css file there by hiding more of your codes sever side

Comment: if your going through all this stress to avoid your css code being visible one can still see your css properties with `F12` or `inspect element`

Comment: Thank you it's working now i was missing a few things which i took from your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PHP's include command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to inject the external PHP:

```
<?php include 'myphpstylesheet.php'; ?>
```

Inside that PHP file, you have a missing PHP closing tag, and the CSS needs to be declared properly within `<style>` tags:

```
<?php
 $bgcolor = '#FF00FF';
?>

<style>
 div #container {
  background-color: <?php echo $bgcolor ; ?>
 }
</style>
```

There's many ways to have dynamic control over CSS.

If you wanted to maintain the  method, and truly feed it a dynamic PHP file, you have to make sure the PHP output is ONLY css. [Here's an article](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/) on that.

Comment: Yes i have that i missed it while typing let me edit it

Comment: Sorry where is the herf errors is that whats making it not to work

Comment: Yea, I saw the `herf` error, but that line is not needed anyhow.

Comment: Thank you sir, i am going through the links in you're answer